# Data Type Mismatch error in Criteria expression in Select query C# query

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

My sample code is as follows, I am getting following error;

> Data Type Mismatch error in  criteria expression.

Details => ScannerAlarmLimits is my table from .mdb database.

```
string jointS = dsetChamberS1.Tables[0].Rows[tot][0].ToString();
int select1S = Convert.ToInt32(jointS);
string sqlQuery1S = "SELECT TMin,TMax,HMin,HMax from ScannerAlarmLimits WHERE ScannerID='" +select1S+ "'";
OleDbCommand cmd1S = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery1S, conn);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1S = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1S);
adapter1S.Fill(dsetTempS, "ScannerAlarmLimits");
```

Comment: What's the type of the ScannerID field, and why aren't you using parameterized SQL?

Comment: ScannerID is Integer..

Comment: Sorry to say but I have less knowledge of parameterized query.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn about parameterized SQL then, *before* your project falls victim to a SQL injection attack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added single quote in the condition of where clause, now its working.

```
var query = "SELECT * from  checkinout where read <> '1'";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `ScannerID` column is integer, then you should not use single quotes with it. Single quotes are for characters. Like;

```
WHERE ScannerID = " + select1S;
```

But as a better way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Aka [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and adapters.

```
string jointS = dsetChamberS1.Tables[0].Rows[tot][0].ToString();
int select1S = Convert.ToInt32(jointS);
using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var cmd1S = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd1S.CommandText = "SELECT TMin,TMax,HMin,HMax from ScannerAlarmLimits WHERE ScannerID = @id";
    cmd1S.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = select1S;

    using(var adapter1S = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1S))
    {
        adapter1S.Fill(dsetTempS, "ScannerAlarmLimits");
    }
}
```